# How to apply the OpenCV-function polylines() to lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, opencv, imshow

I have a result like this `std::list<std::list<cv::Point2i>>` and I would like to visualize the result using `polylines()` and `imshow()`. Is there a way to realize this without having to copy the list elements to vectors?

Comment: no way without copying, lists don't have continuous data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I hadn't thought on whether the data is continuous or not yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. `cv::polylines` accepts only continuously stored data. So it can't process points stored in `std::list`.

If you don't want to store your points in `std::vector` you may implement `polylines` for `std::list`.

For example:

```
void polylines(cv::Mat& img, const std::list<std::list<cv::Point2i>>& polylines)
{
    for (auto& polyline : polylines)
    {
        auto current = polyline.begin();
        auto next = std::next(current, 1);
        for (; next != polyline.end(); current++, next++)
        {
            cv::line(img, *current, *next, cv::Scalar(255));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `cv::imshow` for drawing.